# Why isn't push/pop matrix equivalence necessary in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Consider this OpenGL ES 1.1 code, called every frame:

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(m_currentAngle, 0, 0, 1);

//... enable, point, draw vertices

glPopMatrix();
```

All well and good. Now if I remove the push/pop, I get continuous rotation animation, which makes sense.

However, in ES 2.0, here is the equivalent effect:

```
 //no glRotate so doing this:
float radians = m_currentAngle * 3.14159f / 180.0f;
float s = std::sin(radians);
float c = std::cos(radians);
float zRotation[16] = {
    c, s, 0, 0,
    -s, c, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
};
GLint modelviewUniform = glGetUniformLocation(m_simpleProgram, "Modelview");
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelviewUniform, 1, 0, &zRotation[0]);

//... then enable, point and draw vertices
```

This also creates the proper image, but despite nothing equivalent to a "push/pop" technique, it does *not* continuously rotate. Why does the 2.0 not continuous rotate, while the 1.1 does?

Or phrased another way, why does 1.1 require the push/pop to prevent continuous animation, while 2.0 does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old style pipeline is designed for scene graph usage. When you introduce a new transform, it is concatenated with the current one, so in order to be able to make a scene-graph, you can push the current transform onto the provided stack when visiting child nodes, apply a local transform, do some rendering, and then pop the transform back off again to go back to the parent's transform.

It is also necessary for GL's rendering/lighting pipeline that it can make sense of the matrices used, which is why it is split into 'projection' and 'modelview'.

The new style pipeline does not do any of that. What you are doing in that pipeline is specifying the exact matrix you want to render with. When you specify a different matrix, it simply replaces whatever is there already.

Your example is equivalent to doing:

```
glLoadIdentity()
glRotate()
```

So there is no continuous rotation.

If you want concatenation, pushing, popping, etc. it is up you to implement it yourself. You would need to store the previous matrix value, and multiply it. Or alternatively, update the rotation value.

There are many reasons for this, not least of which is that the programmable pipeline has less of a strict definition of how you might be transforming vertices anyway, so it leaves the construction of the necessary matrices up to the programmer. Perhaps you don't even have a matrix, but construct the transform in the shader.